Changing the Name of an Object Based on the Selected Object with VBA
This macro works by selecting 2 objects. The object that has been previously named is called 'A', and the other object's name is RANDOM. I hope that with this macro, I can change the name of the selected object. If an object named A is found, then the other object is renamed to '1'. Similarly, if an object named B is found, then the other object is renamed to '2', and so on
Sub ChangeObjectName()
    Dim sr As ShapeRange
    Dim s As Shape
    
    Set sr = ActiveSelectionRange
    If sr.Count <> 2 Then Exit Sub
    
    For Each s In sr
        If s.Name <> "A" Then
            s.Name = "1"
        End If
    Next s
End Sub


(https://i.sstatic.net/37n6h.png)
I tried to develop the script to be like this,
Sub ChangeObjectName()
    Dim sr As ShapeRange
    Dim s As Shape
    
    Set sr = ActiveSelectionRange
    If sr.Count <> 2 Then Exit Sub
    
    For Each s In sr
        If s.Name <> "A" Then
            s.Name = "1"
        If s.Name <> "B" Then
            s.Name = "2"
        If s.Name <> "C" Then
            s.Name = "3"
        If s.Name <> "D" Then
            s.Name = "4"
        End If
    Next s
End Sub


However, encountering an error message,
Compile Error, Next without For
I've also attempted looping through the context, but encountered an issue where the object names didn't change as expected. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could assist me in resolving this script. Thank you.

You have 4 If statements but only 1 End If.

I have tried to fix it before by adding End If in each block, but the main issue is, the script does not run as I expected. The object names do not change according to the script.

Please try code with End If after each If ... Then and work from there. What is the error when oyu do that?


Untested code because of w/o coreldraw sw. It is revised as the VBA logic.

Sub ChangeObjectName()
    Dim sr As ShapeRange
    Dim s As Shape, s2 As Shape, s1 As Shape
    Const START_NAME = "A"
    Const END_NAME = "D"
    
    Set sr = ActiveSelectionRange
    If sr.Count <> 2 Then
        MsgBox "Please select two shapes"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each s In sr
        If Len(s.Name) = 1 And s.Name >= START_NAME And s.Name <= END_NAME Then
            Set s1 = s
        Else
            Set s2 = s
        End If
    Next s
    If s1 Is Nothing Or s2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Can't get the shape " & IIf(s1 Is Nothing, "s1", "s2")
        Exit Sub
    Else
       s2.Name = CStr(Asc(s1.Name) - 64)
       MsgBox "New shape name is " & s2.Name
    End If
End Sub


Thank you for answering, but the script still doesn't work

May I know what's the error and which line? Does your first snippet work well?

Your script seems to have no errors, it just doesn't work as I expected.
My previous script at the very top, it should work fine. Then I tried to expand its usage on Object Name B through Z by modifying it like the second script I posted, but when I run the script, the result is not like when I run the first script.

I've added the MsgBox to let you know more about the running status. Please test again.

WOW, your code works !!
Thankyou so much.....
how to send coffee ?

Can you help me for this sir ??
https://stackoverflow.com/q/78286480/22404558
