"VBA CorelDraw "Rename Object A-Z not in order
I have created a script to rename objects in CorelDraw according to alphabetical order. This script should work as expected, but I don't know why the sequence is from Z to A.
Screenshots on the left show the code functioning as intended.
Sub RenameSelectedObjects()
    Dim i As Integer
    Const START_CHAR = 65 ' ASCII untuk 'A'
    Const END_CHAR = 90   ' ASCII untuk 'Z'
    Dim objCount As Integer
    Dim selectedShape As Shape
    
    i = 0
    objCount = ActiveSelectionRange.Count
    
    For Each selectedShape In ActiveSelectionRange
        If i > END_CHAR - START_CHAR Then Exit Sub
        selectedShape.Name = Chr(START_CHAR + i)
        i = i + 1
    Next selectedShape
End Sub


But it's another matter if the 'Object as a whole' succeeds with this script.
Sub RenameObjects()
    Dim i As Integer
    Const START_CHAR = 65 ' ASCII untuk 'A'
    Const END_CHAR = 90   ' ASCII untuk 'Z'
    
    i = 0
    For Each s In ActivePage.Shapes.All
        If i > END_CHAR - START_CHAR Then Exit Sub
        s.Name = Chr(START_CHAR + i)
        i = i + 1
    Next s
   
End Sub

Is there anyone who can assist me in making the script work only on the selected objects and maintaining their order from A to Z?


Since I don't have CorelDRAW software, I'm uncertain whether this issue is related to the sequence in which users select multiple shapes.
Referring to your screenshot, the code could be revised as follows.

Sub RenameSelectedObjects()
    Dim i As Integer
    Const START_CHAR = 65 ' ASCII untuk 'A'
    Const END_CHAR = 90   ' ASCII untuk 'Z'
    Dim objCount As Integer
    Dim selectedShape As Shape
    i = 0
    objCount = ActiveSelectionRange.Count
    If objCount > END_CHAR - START_CHAR Then objCount = END_CHAR - START_CHAR ' **
    For Each selectedShape In ActiveSelectionRange
        selectedShape.Name = Chr(START_CHAR + objCount - i) ' **
        i = i + 1
        If i > END_CHAR - START_CHAR Then Exit Sub
    Next selectedShape
End Sub


https://stackoverflow.com/q/78302430/22404558
can you help me for this sir ?
